# difference between Do Loop until and not operator in while loop?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim n As Integer

Do Until n > 5
   n = n + 10
Loop
Debug.WriteLine(n)
```

VS

```
Dim n As Integer

While Not n > 5
   n = n + 10
End While
Debug.WriteLine(n)
```

output: 10 (in both)

Comment: Is this a contest? What's your question?

Comment: Hahahahaaha cracked me up! Read it with the Street Fighter voice.

Comment: The difference is the same as in: _sleep until it's daylight_ vs _sleep while it's not daylight_. It's the same thing, expressed with slightly different _words_..

Comment: this is not a contest ... if we can use not operator with while thn what is the use of do until ? why vb introduce it ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the `Not` is an extra operator. The result is the same.

You can do the same with the complement to the `>` operator, so that you don't need one operator more:

```
While n <= 5
  n = n + 10
End While
```

You can also do the same with `Do While`:

```
Do While n <= 5
  n = n + 10
Loop
```

The `Do ... Loop` construct is more flexible in that you can use `While` or `Until` at either end of the loop. As `Do ... Loop` can do anything that `While` can, it's kept mostly for backwards compatibility.

Comment: if we can use not operator with while thn what is the use of do until ? why vb introduce it ?

Comment: @salmankhan: The language needed a loop where the condition could also be at the end, like the `repeat ... until` in Pascal or the `do ... while();` in C. Adding one that lets you use `While` or `Until` allows you to write a condition that closer resembles the intention of the code.